# How to add field to menu

Tags: 8, forms

I want to add a description field to my menu and and use it in front.

I managed to have a text_format field for my description (in /admin/structure/menu/manage/main) but when I click on save, that field is empty.

```
function HOOK_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id != 'menu_edit_form') {
    return false;
  }
  $form['field_menu_content'] = array(
   '#type' => 'text_format',
   '#title' => t('Description'),
   '#format' => 'full_html',
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the complete working solution from @4k4 answer:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id != 'menu_edit_form') {
    return false;
  }
  $config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('mymodule.settings');
  $field_menu_content = $config->get('field_menu_content');
  $form['field_menu_content'] = array(
   '#type' => 'text_format',
   '#title' => t('Description'),
   '#default_value' => $field_menu_content['value'],
   '#format' => 'full_html',
  );
  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_menu_edit_submit';
}

function mymodule_menu_edit_submit($form, $form_state) {
  $config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('mymodule.settings');
  $config->set('field_menu_content', $form_state->getValue('field_menu_content'))->save();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/39288049/4629065

Try out [Menu Item Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_extras) module for Drupal 8 from Drupal.org projects site https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_extras.

For more info take a look the next answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46728856/4629065

Answer (score 1):

In hook_form_alter() add a submit function:

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'my_module_menu_edit_submit';
```

Where you store the field:

```
function my_module_menu_edit_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('mymodule.settings');
  $config->set('main_content', $form_state->getValue('field_menu_content'))
    ->save();
}
```

The main menu is hard coded in the settings name. If you want this to work for all menus, you can try to get the menu name from the form. I did not investigate where you can get it.

When you build the form field you also need to get the field value from config. More information: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/simple-configuration-api

Comment: Thank you it's working! There was few typos, I've post the working code.